# Mapping Between LLVM IR and x86 Instructions

Tags: compilation, x86, llvm, debug-symbols

Is there an easy way to map to LLVM instructions from their associated assembly instructions in the output binary?  Given an instruction in an x86 binary, I would like to be able to determine with which LLVM IR instruction it is associated.

One possibility would be to compile the binary with debug symbols turned on and then [associate the instructions based off of source code line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190139/map-between-llvm-ir-instruction-and-line-of-source), but that seems like a hack and is prone to having a many-to-many mapping between x86 and LLVM IR when ideally it would be a many-to-one mapping.